# NotImplementedError using pyusb on Windows10

Tags: python, windows-10, usb, pyusb

I was trying to read the input of a USB device (in this case a USB flash drive). So I strarted with this code:

```py
import usb.core
import usb.backend.libusb1

VENDOR_ID = 0x0951
PRODUCT_ID = 0x1643 



device = usb.core.find(idVendor=VENDOR_ID, idProduct=PRODUCT_ID)
print(device)

if device is None:
    raise ValueError('Device not found')
    sys.exit(1)


usb.util.claim_interface(device, 0)
```

I did obtain a device handle. But a `NotImplementedError` appears after that. (The same happens if I use `device.get_active_configuratio()`):

```
DEVICE ID 0951:1643 on Bus 001 Address 013 =================
 bLength                :   0x12 (18 bytes)
 bDescriptorType        :    0x1 Device
 bcdUSB                 :  0x200 USB 2.0
 bDeviceClass           :    0x0 Specified at interface     
 bDeviceSubClass        :    0x0
 bDeviceProtocol        :    0x0
 bMaxPacketSize0        :   0x40 (64 bytes)
 idVendor               : 0x0951
 idProduct              : 0x1643
 bcdDevice              :  0x100 Device 1.0
 iManufacturer          :    0x1 Error Accessing String
 iProduct               :    0x2 Error Accessing String
 iSerialNumber          :    0x3 Error Accessing String
 bNumConfigurations     :    0x1
  CONFIGURATION 1: 100 mA ==================================
   bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
   bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
   wTotalLength         :   0x20 (32 bytes)
   bNumInterfaces       :    0x1
   bConfigurationValue  :    0x1
   iConfiguration       :    0x0
   bmAttributes         :   0x80 Bus Powered
   bMaxPower            :   0x32 (100 mA)
    INTERFACE 0: Mass Storage ==============================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
     bInterfaceClass    :    0x8 Mass Storage
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x6
     bInterfaceProtocol :   0x50
     iInterface         :    0x0
      ENDPOINT 0x81: Bulk IN ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x200 (512 bytes)
       bInterval        :   0xff
      ENDPOINT 0x2: Bulk OUT ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :    0x2 OUT
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x200 (512 bytes)
       bInterval        :   0xff
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\keylogger\ADU_USB.py", line 17, in <module>
    usb.util.claim_interface(device, 0)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\usb\util.py", line 207, in claim_interface
    device._ctx.managed_claim_interface(device, interface)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 170, in managed_claim_interface
    self.managed_open()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 131, in managed_open
    self.handle = self.backend.open_device(self.dev)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 804, in open_device
    return _DeviceHandle(dev)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 652, in __init__
    _check(_lib.libusb_open(self.devid, byref(self.handle)))
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 600, in _check
    raise NotImplementedError(_strerror(ret))
NotImplementedError: Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform
```

I saw that the error could arise when libusb was not in the path, but in my case I already have it. I would like to know how to fix this error. I also read that the solution might be to use Zoldig driver but I wanted to avoid this solution. Is it possible with Pyserial?

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad format of the scripts

Comment: you appear to be using python 3.11 right?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common issue with `pyusb` that has been raised severally on GitHub such as https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/issues/375 and https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/issues/418 and the likely cause of this error is that the installed driver isn't compatible with `libusb` so you need to install a libusb-compatible driver see [How to use libusb on Windows](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/wiki/Windows#How_to_use_libusb_on_Windows).

Also looking at [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pyusb/), it appears `pyusb` works best for Python versions 3.6 - 3.9.

Comment: Yes thank you I already solved the problem using Zoldig

Comment: I believe you meant to say **Zadig** not Zoldig. Zadig is a Windows application that installs generic USB drivers, such as the libusb compatible driver I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Since the answer helped you, you can accept the answer